# 500 Internal Server Error on Ajax Submission

Tags: ajax, django

I'm getting a 500 error on the submission of an ajax call. I was wondering if you could help me figure out why.

Please note that the csrf_token is added to the data on a seperate javascript (using code under the 'AJAX' section of this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax). My understanding is that if there is a problem with the csrf_token, a 403 error would be thrown.

**Template**

```
<form class="userorder" method='POST' action='.' data-url='{{ request.build_absolute_uri|safe }}'>

    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.couponcode.errors }}

    <div class="coupon_message"></div>

    <div id="couponcodevalue">{{form.couponcode}}</div>

    <div id="couponcodeapply">Apply</div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

$("#couponcodeapply").click(function(){

    var coupon = $("#id_couponcode").val()
    var data = {coupon: coupon,}    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/getcoupon/",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#coupon-message").text("Coupon Added")    
        },
        error: function(response, error) {                
            $("#coupon-message").text("Coupon Not Added")    
        }             
     })        
});              

</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def getcoupon(request):

    print("I am in getcoupon")

    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "hi"

        data = {
            'message': message,
            }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**Error in Console (Chrome)**

```
 jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/getcoupon/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):1636
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Is there any way to get additional detail on why this 500 code is being thrown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to import Jsonresponse into the view!

from django.http import JsonResponse